# Characterization of functions with fractional expansion near zero

Tags: taylor-expansion, fractional-calculus

I would like to understand if it is possible to completely characterize real-valued functions with an expansion of this type:

$f(x)=f'(0)\cdot x + o(x^{\alpha})\qquad \alpha \in (1,2)$

I am not familiar with fractional calculus, so even though the question seems reasonable I have troubles finding references.

Thanks to anyone who can point me out in the right direction!